# jQuery - How to combine Two select lists into One text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two select lists I'm trying to combine into one text input. (https://jsfiddle.net/ecg6a3fL)

I got it working for the value, but not the text for some reason.

Changing it to `.text()` rather than `.val()` produces an odd result (showing                    `Jan          Feb          Mar          Apr          May          Jun          Jul          Aug          Sep          Oct          Nov          Dec        ,                     2020          2021`       )

In addition, I have these separated by a "comma space"... if anyone can help for this delimiter to not show if only one of either select box is selected, that would be very much appreciated!

An example goal is for it to display: "Jan, 2020" or "Jan" or "2020"

Thank you for your help!

HTML and jQuery:

```js
$('#edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month, #edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year').change(function() {
   var combined = $('#edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month').text() +', '+ $('#edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year').text();
   $("#edit-field-report-last-seen-cached-und-0-value").val(combined);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value" class="date-padding clearfix">
    <div class="control-group form-type-select form-item-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month form-item">
      <label for="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month" class="control-label">Month </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="date-month">
          <select class="date-clear form-select" id="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month" name="field_report_last_seen[und][0][value][month]">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="1">Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
            <option value="4">Apr</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">Jun</option>
            <option value="7">Jul</option>
            <option value="8">Aug</option>
            <option value="9">Sep</option>
            <option value="10">Oct</option>
            <option value="11">Nov</option>
            <option value="12">Dec</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-type-select form-item-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year form-item">
      <label for="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year" class="control-label">Year </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="date-year">
          <select class="date-clear form-select" id="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year" name="field_report_last_seen[und][0][value][year]">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="text-full form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-report-last-seen-cached-und-0-value" name="field_report_last_seen_cached[und][0][value]" value="" size="20" maxlength="50">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below :

```js
$('#edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month, #edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year').change(function() {
  $("#edit-field-report-last-seen-cached-und-0-value").val($("#edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value select").map(function() {
    //not first value...
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      return $(this).find("option:selected").text()
    }
  }).get().join(', ')); //join values

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value" class="date-padding clearfix">
  <div class="control-group form-type-select form-item-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month form-item">
    <label for="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month" class="control-label">Month </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="date-month">
        <select class="date-clear form-select" id="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-month" name="field_report_last_seen[und][0][value][month]">
          <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option>
          <option value="2">Feb</option>
          <option value="3">Mar</option>
          <option value="4">Apr</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
          <option value="6">Jun</option>
          <option value="7">Jul</option>
          <option value="8">Aug</option>
          <option value="9">Sep</option>
          <option value="10">Oct</option>
          <option value="11">Nov</option>
          <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group form-type-select form-item-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year form-item">
    <label for="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year" class="control-label">Year </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="date-year">
        <select class="date-clear form-select" id="edit-field-report-last-seen-und-0-value-year" name="field_report_last_seen[und][0][value][year]">
          <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
          <option value="2021">2021</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input class="text-full form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-report-last-seen-cached-und-0-value" name="field_report_last_seen_cached[und][0][value]" value="" size="20" maxlength="50">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't appear to work. Produces "1,2020" when the goal is for it to display: "Jan, 2020" or "Jan" or "2020"

Comment: updated .. i though issue was with commas :P sorry i missunderstood your question .

Comment: Oh no problem, this looks great! Any chance we can get the "comma space" working for when both fields are joined? I see it's currently missing the space.

Comment: just added space here `join(' , ')` .

Comment: Excellent, I did the same but for sake of getting it right, thought I would mention. BTW, you have one extra space before the comma. It's perfect though, thank you!